# SQL Query for data update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query to update some data from two tables

My table data is in below format

```
PAN         email
---------------------------------------------------
ABC1234567  email1
ABC1234567  email2
ABD2345678  email3
```

I want to convert it like this:

```
PAN         E1      E2      E3      E4      E5
---------------------------------------------------
ABC1234567  email1  email2  
ABD2345678  email3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Kindly refer to this [ask].

Comment: Not enough sample data to produce the expected output. Is there any other column value that has indication for value in PAN and email 1 to 5?

Comment: No indication. there are 2200000 records and for 1 pan no there are multiple emails which needs to be converted in columns

Comment: @shwetapipaliya, Are you able to say, what will be the maximum number of mail for a PAN number?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. This will give up-to 5 email ids for a **PAN** number.

```
SELECT D.PAN
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN D.EmailId ELSE '' END)E1
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN=2 THEN D.EmailId ELSE '' END)E2
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN=3 THEN D.EmailId ELSE '' END)E3
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN=4 THEN D.EmailId ELSE '' END)E4
     ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN=5 THEN D.EmailId ELSE '' END)E5
FROM(
    SELECT PAN, 
        EmailId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PAN ORDER BY PAN) RN
    FROM YourTable
    )D
GROUP BY PAN
```